# How to add break in combobox list from external XML file?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, combobox

I am pulling through a datadic.xml file to populate a combobox in actionscript 3.0 but I want to add a break or a title between each section for the top 11 attributes then break and then the last 26 attributes. This is part of my xml file:

```
<codeSet> 
<title>Census: population estimates for Northern Ireland </title>
<subtitle>By country, region and local authority</subtitle>
<txtSource>2011 Census</txtSource>
<txtSource2>2001Census</txtSource2>
<dateStart>2001</dateStart>
<dateEnd>2011</dateEnd>
<code id='94NI'>NORTHERN IRELAND</code>
<code id='N09000001'>Antrim and Newtownabbey</code>
```

Then the actionscript loads the xml and create a function called setLists which is a simple loop to populate the combobox but now I want to put a break so should be Northern Ireland(break)Antrim and Newtownabbey followed by 10 then (break) and so on. ActionScript code:

```
function setLists():void
{
    var menuLength:int = xmlCodes.code.length();
    for (var i:int=0; i<menuLength; i++)
        {
            myVarList1.addItem({label:xmlCodes.code[i].text(), data:xmlCodes.code[i].@id});
            myVarList2.addItem({label:xmlCodes.code[i].text(), data:xmlCodes.code[i].@id});

            if (

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's always going to be the same number of elements beneath the titles, try something like this:

```
function setLists():void
{
    var menuLength:int = xmlCodes.code.length();

    // I'm basing the "breaks" variable on this flow: title, break, 11 items, break, title, break, 26 items
    // 
    var breaks:int = 3;
    var breakCount:int = 0;
    // Note we've added "breaks" to our menuLength
    //
    for (var i:int=0; i<menuLength + breaks; i++)
        {
            // 1, 12, and 14 are where we add breaks based on the flow mentioned above
            //
            if (i == 1 || i == 12 || i == 14) {
                myVarList1.addItem({label:' ', data:null);
                myVarList2.addItem({label:' ', data:null);
                breakCount++;
            } else {
                myVarList1.addItem({label:xmlCodes.code[i-breakCount].text(), data:xmlCodes.code[i].@id});
                myVarList2.addItem({label:xmlCodes.code[i-breakCount].text(), data:xmlCodes.code[i].@id});
            }
        }
```

Comment: So I have it that there are breaks in the correct place but when you click an empty label it expects data to be there and crashes the flash application. Is there any way to have it so you cant click on the breaks. Also why is the breaks variable set to 3?

Comment: Can't think of a way to stop clicks on break, but if you modify your function that checks the selected item's data to check for null or some other custom data you choose (like breaker, or something) and have it throw an error message directing the user to make sure they select an actual option. I thought you wanted 3 breaks; one after the first title, one before the next title and one after that title. Adjust as needed.

Comment: Ah Yes sorry stupid moment, but thank you for your help got it working eventually much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there's a difference in the `id` format between the "categories" and their "children"? Also, the XML provides a sorted list with the following pattern?

> - CATEGORY1
> - child1
> - child2
> - [...]
> - child3
> - CATEGORY2
> - child1
> - child2
> - [...]
> - child3

If so you can try to figure out what differentiates the ID's between the "categories" and their "children". One way to do that would be to create a [regular expression](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html) that matches only ID's belonging to categories and act differently when you get a match.

Example:

```
var categoryIdPattern:RegExp = /^\d{2,3}\w{2,3}$/; // Matches only strings consisting of 2-3 numbers followed by 2-3 word characters

var menuLength:int = xmlCodes.code.length();
for (var i:int = 0; i < menuLength; i++) {
    myVarList1.addItem({label:xmlCodes.code[i].text(), data:xmlCodes.code[i].@id});
    if (categoryIdPattern.exec(xmlCodes.code[i].@id as String) != null) {
        //This is a category, add an empty row beneath the newly added value in the combobox
        myVarList1.addItem({label:"", data:null});
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I should add that the above code is untested and only illustrates the concept.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in the end was created a new class to override the data setter so I could set the value to 'disabled:true' in the combobox

```
var myVarList1:ComboBox = new ComboBox();
var myVarList2:ComboBox = new ComboBox();
myVarList1.dropdown.setStyle("cellRenderer", MyCustomCellRenderer); 
myVarList2.dropdown.setStyle("cellRenderer", MyCustomCellRenderer);
```

then when calling my setlists function

```
function setLists():void
    {
        var menuLength:int = xmlCodes.code.length();
        var breaks:int = 3;
        var breaksCount:int = 0;

    for (var i:int=0; i<menuLength; i++)
        {

            if(i == 1){

                myVarList1.addItem({label: " ", disabled:true});
                myVarList2.addItem({label: " ", disabled:true});                
                breaksCount++;
            }
                else if (i == 11){
                myVarList1.addItem({label: " ", disabled:true});
                myVarList2.addItem({label: " ", disabled:true});                    
                breaksCount++;
                }

            else {

            myVarList1.addItem({label:xmlCodes.code[i].text(), data:xmlCodes.code[i].@id});
            myVarList2.addItem({label:xmlCodes.code[i].text(), data:xmlCodes.code[i].@id});
            }
        }
```

This is the custom function to allow you to set the value to disabled.

```
package { 
    import fl.controls.listClasses.CellRenderer; 
    public class MyCustomCellRenderer extends CellRenderer
    {
        // override the data setter to set the enabled flag
        override public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
            super.data = value;    
            this.enabled = !(value['disabled']);
        }
    } 
}
```